# Local notebook server using a gateway server for kernel management, writing to a local file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, gateway

I have a Jupyter notebook server running on my local machine, with [a gateway server running on a more powerful/remote machine](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#using-a-gateway-server-for-kernel-management).

I can write to a file on the remote machine with normal code in a normal notebook, but I can't figure out how to write to a file on my local machine.  Is there some `%magic` command for being able to execute code locally, or any mechanism to access a local file, when using a gateway server?